# Mirror displays, but change orientation

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, mate

Is there a simple way to mirror displays but change the orientation?
I'm on Ubuntu Mate 20.04, I have a smart board hooked up next to me,
the orientation of which is opposite the screen. I want mirroring,
but the screen needs to be flipped.
Using the mate-display utility, no such option is immediately available.
Im just looking for a simple way to do this.

(being the absolute psychopath I am, I needed the solution last night, so I popped the screen mount out the back of my monitor, drilled some new mounting holes, and set the rotation to "upside down" but I can't advise this as a solution

[image: Orientation hack]

Comment: I set a shortcut key to 

xrandr --output eDP --rotate inverted

eDp from your xinput for your monitor
and for touchscreen realignment
 xinput set-prop 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen Stylus (0)' --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1 && xinput map-to-output 'ELAN0732:00 04F3:2536 Pen Stylus (0)' eDP && xinput map-to-output 14 eDP 

searching for those terms might get you a thread I did here in more details.

Answer (score 0):

I could manage getting that with Xorg session in Dell M4800 laptop with `nouveau` driver. Following these steps

1. You have to be in Xorg session. If you are using Wayland, logout and switch it.
2. Check current output with: `xrandr`
3. Invert target output, example:

   ```
   ## It is always good to have backup plan. run this first so you can go back quickly.
   ## (<up> then <enter> to switch back to normal)
   xrandr --verbose --output LVDS-1 --rotate normal --output DP-3 --rotate normal

   xrandr --verbose --output LVDS-1 --rotate normal --output DP-3 --rotate inverted
   ```
4. Mine go ugly, I have Gnome-shell with Nvidia. I got 2nd screen inverted and 1st screen black with system log (like last TTY).

   Quick workaround switch to another TTY console then back.

   Myself switched to TTY1 which has login screen then back to TTY2, now they appear correctly.